# Scala: How to take any generic sequence as input to this method

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

Scala noob here. Still trying to learn the syntax.

I am trying to reduce the code I have to write to convert my test data into DataFrames. Here is what I have right now:

```
  def makeDf[T](seq: Seq[(Int, Int)], colNames: String*): Dataset[Row] = {
    val context = session.sqlContext
    import context.implicits._
    seq.toDF(colNames: _*)
  }
```

The problem is that the above method only takes a sequence of the shape `Seq[(Int, Int)]` as input. How do I make it take any sequence as input? I can change the inputs shape to `Seq[AnyRef]`, but then the code fails to recognize the `toDF` call as valid symbol.

I am not able to figure out how to make this work. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, Spark doesn't support AnyRef in udf()s..

Comment: as i can see you took the generic type T but didn't used it and toDF method is on seq so what you can do is make it of type Seq[T] then it should work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag

def makeDf[T <: Product: TypeTag](seq: Seq[T], colNames: String*): DataFrame = ...
```

Explanation:

When you are calling seq.toDF you are actually using an implicit defined in SQLImplicits:

```
implicit def localSeqToDatasetHolder[T : Encoder](s: Seq[T]): DatasetHolder[T] = {
  DatasetHolder(_sqlContext.createDataset(s))
}
```

which in turn requires the generation of an encoder. The problem is that encoders are defined only on certain types. Specifically Product (i.e. tuple, case class etc.) You also need to add the TypeTag implicit so that Scala can get over the type erasure (in the runtime all Sequences have the type sequence regardless of the generics type. TypeTag provides information on this).

As a side node, you do not need to extract sqlcontext from the session, you can simply use:

```
import sparkSession.implicits._
```

Answer (score 1):

As @AssafMendelson already explained the real reason of why you cannot create a `Dataset` of `Any` is because **Spark** needs an `Encoder` to transform *objects* from they **JVM** *representation* to its internal *representation* - and **Spark** cannot guarantee the generation of such `Encoder` for *`Any`* type.

Assaf answers is correct, and will work.
However, IMHO, it is too much restrictive as it will only work for `Products` *(tuples, and case classes)* - and even if that includes most use cases, there still a few ones excluded.

Since, what you really need is an `Encoder`, you may leave that responsibility to the client. Which in most situation will only need to call `import spark.implicits._` to get them in scope.
Thus, this is what I believe will be the most general solution.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, Dataset, Encoder, SparkSession}

// Implicit SparkSession to make the call to further methods more transparent.
implicit val spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
import spark.implicits._

def makeDf[T: Encoder](seq: Seq[T], colNames: String*)
                      (implicit spark: SparkSession): DataFrame =
  spark.createDataset(seq).toDF(colNames: _*)

def makeDS[T: Encoder](seq: Seq[T])
                      (implicit spark: SparkSession): Dataset[T] =
  spark.createDataset(seq)
```

***Note:** This is basically re-inventing the already defined functions from Spark.*